# Hyper-V unplanned save and restore of VM

Tags: hyper-v

2 x Server 2008 R2 VM's in a failover cluster, a guest running Server 2008 R2 with SQL 2008 Standard running has saved and then restored the past two evenings at 6pm (doesn't migrate, just stays on the same host).

I have checked scheduled tasks on all the OS's and event logs but nothing to say why this has happened only that it has happened.

One thing worth mentioning, this error appears after restore and another VM on the other host is running large print run.
Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: 64 Bit HP BiDi Channel Components Installer. Product Version: 1.2.0.2. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.

Comment: Verify your hosts are not over subscribed.  Also verify the SQL server guest can live migrate between hosts.

Comment: This has 20GB ram, other vm has 2gb, host has 48gb.  I'll look at the microsoft guides on guest vm's to see if any other factors apply.  Will try a migrate later.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a shot in the dark, but it sounds like something tried to take a snapshot of the shared storage.  This will trigger a save/restore cycle of the VM if you don't have the VSS integration component running in the guest.

Comment: We are running DPM 2010, I will check these logs.